# How to add (or copy) a new userform in VBA using code inside a Module (not Insert Button)

Tags: excel, vba, forms, dynamic, userform

I need to be able to have identical userforms open simultaneously as a user needs to access info from a dataset to update entries.
Each userform will have the same text boxes, command boxes, etc.
So the userform needs to be of structure userform(i).

How do I create the userforms dynamically? The user selects ID# and new form is created.
I can handle the loops and passing the name into the form to update all the references, but it’s the making a dynamic copy in code that has me completely stumped.

I was thinking the code would be something like:

```
 Dim frm As UserForm
 Set frm = UserForms.Add
 frm.Name = "NewName_i"
```

I would then have a loop that would look for how many "NewName_i" exists using Forms.Count and Forms.Visible and then would just add one more as it is needed.

But I cannot get past the creating of a new form dynamically with code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the same form (e.g.) 5 times then you can do something like this:

```vb
Dim colForms As Collection 'holds references to the opened forms

Sub TestForms()
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set colForms = New Collection
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim f As frmTestx
        Set f = New frmTestx
        f.Show vbModeless 'if not modeless then code stops here...
        colForms.Add f
    Next i
End Sub
```